# Add event listeners to multiple video.js players on the same page

Tags: javascript, events, video.js

I've add multiple videojs elements on same page and i want to use same events to them. I trying to load them inside a new array but isnt working correctly. Can you help me figure out put this to work?

```
var myPlayers = Array(_V_("video1"), _V_("video2"));
myPlayers.ready(function () {
   var myPlayer = this;
   myPlayer.on("pause", function () {
      $('#'+myPlayer+' #accordion-section-title').removeClass('playing');
   });
   myPlayer.on("play", function () {
      $('#'+myPlayer+' #accordion-section-title').addClass('playing');
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array doesn't inherit the methods of its members, so you can't simply call `ready()` on the array. You need to loop through it, and then act on each element.

You should also use the videojs player's `id()` method to get the player id to build your selector for jQuery.

```
var myPlayers = Array(videojs("video1"), videojs("video2"));
myPlayers.forEach(function (player) {
  player.on("pause", function () {
    $('#'+ player.id() +' #accordion-section-title').removeClass('playing');
  });
  player.on("play", function () {
    $('#'+ player.id() +' #accordion-section-title').addClass('playing');
  });
});
```

Note I've also replaced the deprecated `_V_` with `videojs`.

Comment: that works! – how can I pause other videos when start other one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18719762/1831907

Comment: 'VIDEOJS: Ignoring already initialized player' I am getting this log