# VideoJS - when playing video, pausing all other videos

Tags: jquery, video, video.js

I created a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Lz3vkwmw/). I play the first video, then as I go to play the second video, the first video should pause. I am not sure what I am missing? Any help would be much appreciated!

```
 $(".video-js").each(function (videoIndex) {
    var videoId = $(this).attr("id");

    _V_(videoId).ready(function(){
        this.on("play", function(e) {
            //pause other video
            $(".video-js").each(function (index) {
                if (videoIndex !== index) {
                    this.player.pause();
                }
            });
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pause all playing VideoJS instances on page when one is started?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769051/how-can-i-pause-all-playing-videojs-instances-on-page-when-one-is-started)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because of two reasons:

1. You have not icluded the javascript file for the videojs framework.
2. You are trying to use older deprecated version with `_V_`. The latest one uses `videojs`.

See the updated fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/Lz3vkwmw/1/

For your reference, the code is here :

```
$(".video-js").each(function (videoIndex) {

    var videoId = $(this).attr("id");

    videojs(videoId).ready(function(){
        this.on("play", function(e) {
            //pause other video
            $(".video-js").each(function (index) {
                if (videoIndex !== index) {
                    this.player.pause();
                }
            });
        });

    });
});
```